# error with addEventListener on form submit

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some king of a bookmark app and I need to get value of user input. What's wrong with the code? Console says: **Uncaught TypeError: bookmarkForm.addEventListenter is not a function**

```
(function bookmarkApp() {
  'use strict';
  //lister for form submit
  var bookmarkForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
  bookmarkForm.addEventListenter('submit',  function saveBookmark(e) {
    //get form values
    var siteName = document.getElementById('siteName');
    console.log(siteName);
    //preventDefault
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})();
```

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using proper spellings for method.

```
.addEventListener()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in that function call.

It's correctly spelled `addEventListener`. You wrote addEventListen**t**er

Comment: Oh thanks, I'm so inattentive and my IDE is not even showing anything. It's just like me